# Overlaying tables

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, graphics, fancytooltips

I have two tables as follows:

Table 1:

```
Row/Column | C1 | C2 | C3
ROW 1      | v  | v  | v
ROW 2      | v  | v  | v
ROW 3      | v  | v  | v
ROW 4      | v  | v  | v
ROW 5      | v  | v  | v
...
ROW n    | v | v | v
```

Table 2:

```
Row/Column | C1 
Row1       | v
Row2       | v
Row3       | v
```

I want to have table 1 as a background (possibly transparent) and Table 2 on top of 1 as if it summarize the content of table 1 from ROW 1 up to ROW 4.

What packages do you recommend for doing this?

Answer (score 9):

A simple way to do this would be to just fade out the text that want to be *underneath*. By using [the `array` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package I have defined two new column types, `L` and `C` for left and centered columns which have the text displayed with color `gray!25`. For the entries that you want on *top*, I used `\multicolumn` so that the color would not be applied.

[image]

### Further Enhancements:

- [The `collcell`  package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) could be used to keep track of the current row and column and only apply the gray color if the current entry was outside of the range of the entries that are to be on *top*.

  This would allow the table to be entered as a normal table, and the specification of which entries on top would be separated form the content.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\color{gray!25}}c<{}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\color{gray!25}}l<{}}

\newcommand*{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}%
\newcommand*{\ml}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{L  C  C  C} 
\ml{Row/Column} & \mc{C1} & C2 & C3 \\ \toprule
\ml{ROW 1}      & \mc{v}  & v  & v  \\ 
\ml{ROW 2}      & \mc{v}  & v  & v  \\ 
\ml{ROW 3}      & \mc{v}  & v  & v  \\  %\cmidrule{1-4}
    ROW 4       &     v   & v  & v  \\ 
    ROW 5       &     v   & v  & v  \\ 
    ROW n       &     v   & v  & v  \\  %\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Peter. I should have mentioned that the second table contain different (but related) information so it is not C1 in the first table.

Comment: @DotNet: I would be helpful if you updated the question to provide the actual LaTeX code for the two tables with data that better represented your actual use case.  There may be additional complications depending on the data.